# (Android)How to download my db from PC to phone

Tags: android, connection

I wrote a android app and it need use database

The database is save at "data/data/packegename/database"

I want to download my .db file to "data/data/packegename/database/"

but I don't want to root my phone

Is there any easy way to download it to the folder?(I need to copy it very often)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to root your phone, you cannot access your own app data directory except your application process itself.

OptionOne - write some backdoor code in your own application, which will download the db from your PC (setup a webservice)

OptionTwo - setup a tiny web service (as easy as a google away) in your own application, and upload the db from PC

Comment: I use eclipse to write the app,can I download it with app when I "Run" the code?Where I can put my db file?

Comment: That's easy. You can setup a simple web service on your PC (e.g. winappsvr for windows or Apache2 for linux). Simply put your DB file in your www directory. When your application start, before you load your content provider or database stuff, start a simple httpconnection to download the db files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `run-as` command to impersonate your app through adb. See the blogpost [Read Android Data Folder Without Rooting](http://denniskubes.com/2012/09/25/read-android-data-folder-without-rooting/). Your app must be build with the debug flag for this method to work. You can then do things like

```
adb shell "stty raw; run-as your.application.package.name cat /data/data/your.application.package.name/files/whatever.file" > whatever.file
```

However there are some line ending / encoding issues when transfering binary data, at least on windows. You can circumvent that by copying the file to the sdcard, and then pulling from there (if your application has the permissions for that), or by changing the file to world-readable (then you can `adb pull` the file directly).